# matplotlib set yaxis label size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, graphing

How can I change the size of only the yaxis label?
Right now, I change the size of all labels using

```py
pylab.rc('font', family='serif', size=40)
```

but in my case, I would like to make the y-axis label larger than the x-axis. However, I'd like to leave the tick labels alone.

I've tried, for example:

```py
pylab.gca().get_ylabel().set_fontsize(60)
```

but I only get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_fontsize'
```

So, obviously that doesn't work. I've seen lots of stuff for tick sizes, but nothing for the axis labels themselves.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If you are using the 'pylab' for interactive plotting you can set the labelsize at creation time with `pylab.ylabel('Example', fontsize=40)`.

If you use `pyplot` programmatically you can either set the fontsize on creation with `ax.set_ylabel('Example', fontsize=40)` or afterwards with `ax.yaxis.label.set_size(40)`.

Answer (score 0):

`ax.get_ylabel()` returns a string, which doesn't define a `set_fontsize` method but `ax.yaxis.get_label()` returns a `matplotlib.text.Text` object, which does; so the following can be used to change fontsize of ylabel as well.

```py
ax.yaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(40)
```

You can also change the position of the ylabel by calling `set()` on `Text` object:

```py
ax.yaxis.get_label().set(fontsize=40, position=[0.5,0.7])
```