# savefig - text chopped off

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I create a plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.clf()
import numpy as np
props = np.random.randint(0,100,(200,))
x=np.arange(1,201,1)
plt.plot(x,props,c='k')
plt.xlabel('blah blah blah blah blah blah\n blah blah blah blah blah')
plt.ylabel('blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah')
fig=plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(3.75,3.75)#14, 23)
plt.savefig('testfig.png',dpi=300)
```

When using Ipython (via Spyder), the plot presents ok. However when I looked at the saved image, it presents thus:

[image]

As you can see, the text is cut off. **What is recommended practice for dealing with this?**

I have got round it by increasing the figure size, and re-sizing afterwards. However, my aim is to produce a set of images with a consistent text size (figure size varies); so this approach is not ideal.

**Note.** Whilst [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086) exists, this question is distinct in that it:

- deals with both `xlabel` and `ylabel`.
- combines with `set_size_inches`function
- seeks to ensure consistent text size with differing figure sizes.
- seeks to find out why Ipython output differs
  from savefig

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The Ipython console in Spyder uses the `inline` backend, which saves the figure as png and displays the output image. When saving, it uses the option `bbox_inches = "tight"`.

So in order to obtain the same figure as shown in the console, you may decide to use this option as well - it basically extends or shrinks the bounding box such that all objects in the canvas are displayed.

```
plt.savefig('testfig.png',dpi=300, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

Alternatively, you can make sure that all objects are already inside the figure boundaries before saving or showing the figure. This can either be accomplished using

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

which tries to do that automatically, or you can use

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3, right=0.9, bottom=0.3, top=0.9)
```

where the parameters denote the margins on each side in units of fractions of figure size (30% space on the left, 10% space on the right, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

matplotlib has a function called [tight_layout](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) , which *automatically adjusts subplot params so that the subplot(s) fits in to the figure area.*

As stated in the docs, it's flagged as *experimental*, but is commonly used.

In my experience it should be called as late as possible (e.g. before using savefig) and probably after calls which change the geometry (like `fig.set_size_inches`).

In the `plt.show()` gui-window, one of the buttons is doing exactly this call too.

(converted to answer from earlier comment)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is given [elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404759/matplotlib-set-yaxis-label-size).
Briefly, you should chane the fontsize of your label-text:

```
plt.ylabel('Example', fontsize=40)
plt.xlabel('Example', fontsize=40)
```

Of course, change the number 40 (trial and error) to a more suitable value.

I don't know if this is a fix or a work-around.
And neither do I know if this helps.